# Bluetooth OBDII / ELM giving duplicate data as response

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, obd-ii, elm327

I a HC-05 connected to an Arduino's Serial 3. I have also been able to successfully pair with an OBD2-ELM adapter in the car,

I have a code in my sketch to do simple communications with the OBD/ELM

```
if (Serial3.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial3.read());
}
if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial3.write(Serial.read());
}
```

The challenge is this:
If I type ATZ, I get "ELM327 v2.1>"
I type ATTP5, I get "OK>"
Typing ATRV, returns "12.6"
But if I type 0105 I get different responses such as:
**"LM327410v2 ELMv241 M2.11099"**, or **"OK>LM7v41A"** or **"OK> OK > 41055.1 327v"**

Other times I get the correct response of **"4105 5A >"**

I get the same result when I type in 0100 or any other PID code.

Please does anyone have an idea as to what might be causing this and how to
fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, remember that by default, the ELM327 adapter response termination is `\r>` (you can change this via `ATL1`). Directly printing this on a console will lead to problems. Try replacing `\r` with `\n` and then you should see a better output, e.g.:

```
>ATRV
11.9V

>0100
18 DA F1 10 06 41 00 B8 7B 30 10 00
18 DA F1 17 06 41 00 80 00 80 03 00
```

The actual output of course varies with whether you send a PID (such as `0100`) or an internal ELM327 command (such as `ATRV`).